# How can I make a note repeat endlessly when I hold down a key in Garageband?

Tags: midi, virtual-instrument, garage-band

I have a MIDI keyboard connected to the Apple GarageBand DAW (digital audio workstation) app. Is there an effect setting where I can have a note repeat at a set interval (or tempo) when I hold down a note on the keyboard? Kind of like an infinite echo effect that doesn't fade out?

Answer (score 4):

You would need to find a (commercial paid or free) third-party AU (Audio Unit) plug-in such as a synthesizer instrument that includes a *MIDI arpeggiator* to use within GarageBand. This is a virtual device that will repeat the notes in a chord that you hold down on the keyboard in a pre-defined *sequenced* arpeggio pattern which is synced to the tempo of the GarageBand track to which you are recording a part. As the name would imply, arpeggiators are chiefly for working with chord patterns, but I think you could find one that would work on a single note as well.

You might also have success with an AU plugin that provides an *audio looper*, which would accomplish a similar effect with audio rather than with MIDI.

Do a Google search on "virtual instrument arpeggiator" or "virtual instrument looper" and see if you can find a suitable plug-in that is GarageBand-compatible.

Comment: +1, although because GarageBand uses audio units instead of virtual instruments, I would search for "audio unit arpeggiator."

Comment: No, you misunderstand the use of the term. The term "virtual instrument" refers to all computer apps that can be played like a musical instrument, regardless of their platform or format. "Audio Unit" or AU, is the name of Apple's plug-in architecture. Other plug-in formats include VST (Steinberg) and RTAS (Avid Pro Tools). So virtual instruments may be stand-alone apps, and/or plug-ins in VST or AU or RTAS or many other formats. And many virtual instrument apps are available from their creator in multiple plug-in formats.